# Why does the differential form of Gauss' law gives $div\vec g=-4\pi G \rho=0$ outside the earth, when in fact it isn't zero?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Say we want to calculate the gravitational force at a point outside a mass and
consider the differential form of Gauss' law:

$$\text{div }\vec g=-4\pi G \rho$$

where $\vec g$ is the acceleration at the point in question, $G$ the gravitational constant and $\rho$ the mass density at the point in question.

Because $\rho$ is zero at every point outside the mass, so is $\text{div }\vec g$. That means that we only know that the divergence of $\vec g$ is zero at every point. So we don't know $\vec g$ itself. Now $\text{div }\vec g$ outside, for example, the earth isn't zero. It is directed towards the center of the earth and is perpendicular to surfaces (which are in the case of the earth spherical) on which the potential is constant. So why gives Gauss' law in differential form the value zero for $\text{div }\vec g$  at a point outside the earth?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): If the word _it_ in the title is supposed to refer to the divergence, then it is zero.

Comment: The divergence of a vector field is a scalar.  It it not directed toward the center of the Earth, or any other direction.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! It's, of course, the gravitational force (proportional to $divU$) that is perpendicular to surfaces of constant potential.

Answer (score 6):

SHORT ANSWER:

$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec g = 0$ does not imply that $\vec g$ is constant!

---

LONG ANSWER:

As you correctly argued we suspect $\vec{g}$ to be pointing in our outwards from the center such that we should use spherical coordinates to describe the situation.

[Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) tells us that the divergence in spherical coordinates can be written as:

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{g} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial \left( r^2 g_r \right)}{\partial r} + \left[\text{terms that are 0 due to spherical symmetry, e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\cdots)$}\right]$$

Setting this to zero gives us $\frac{\partial \left( r^2 g_r \right)}{\partial r} = 0$, for which the general solution is

$$g_r = \frac{C_{te}}{r^2},$$

which is the correct behavior.

Comment: I was wrong in assuming that $\vec \nabla \vec g=0$ outside the earth.

Comment: @descheleschilder I think I know what you are trying to say, but look carefully at what you *did* say.   Note that $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{g}$ *is indeed zero* outside of the Earth.

Comment: No you are correct: $\vec \nabla \vec g = \rho(\text{outside earth})=0$ your interpretation was wrong.  This is what I showed in my answer $\vec \nabla \vec g = 0$ leads to the $r^{-2}$ dependance of the gravitational field...

It is only "inside the earth" that $\vec \nabla \vec g \neq 0$

Comment: Yes, off course...What I meant to say in my comment is that I was wrong in assuming that $\vec \nabla \vec g$ is **not** zero outside the earth.

Comment: Great so you got understand it now ? If you want me to I could add a small part where I integrate the equation that may give some additional insight as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that $$\mathop{\rm div} \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = 0, \quad \forall \vec{r} \neq 0.$$

Comment: This might be better if you added some more details (it's already been flagged for low-quality)

Answer (score 0):

For point mass, $\rho =M\delta (\mathbf{r})$

\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3} \right)
  &= 4\pi \delta (\mathbf{r}) \\
  \mathbf{g} &= -\frac{GM\mathbf{r}}{r^3} \\
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{g}
  &= -4\pi GM \delta (\mathbf{r}) \\
  &= -4\pi G \rho
\end{align*}

**One more illustration**

For uniform sphere of radius $a$,

$$\rho=
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \dfrac{3M}{4\pi a^3} & , & r \le a \\[3pt]
    0 & , & r > a
  \end{array}
\right.$$

$$\mathbf{g}=
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \dfrac{GM\mathbf{r}}{a^3} & , & r \le a \\[3pt]
    \dfrac{GM\mathbf{r}}{r^3} & , & r > a
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Note that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{r} = 3$

Comment: This is the law I was referring to in my question and doesn't provide  an answer.